# Custom Calendar View in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, view, sharepoint-2010, calendar, web-parts

I'm trying to replicate this mock-up of an intranet site for our HR department:

[image]

However, I can't seem to be able to replicate the look and feel of the calendar. When I tried it, this was what it looked like:

[image]

Is there a way for me to edit the out-of-the-box calendar web part to resemble the one in the markup?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making your own custom calendar webpart that has a list property that allows you to specify which list to display.  Unless you are wanting to use the built-in features of the default SharePoint calendar view it is better to do this on your own using html/css generated by your webpart.  Modifying the default SharePoint calendar's existing styles will be a pain and it might break some of the functionality.

Comment: Thanks for this :) I was afraid that would be the case :( I haven't done much custom web part creation. Is there a good tutorial that you can point me to?